# Excel fixing columns

Tags: excel

I have an excel worksheet with 150,000 lines of data. Some of the data are in the wrong columns how can I fix this

```
Name  Month  Year  Date
May   Chad   1993  04
Kyle  June   23    1989
Alex  Sept   1990  05
```

Comment: Assuming that your data looks exactly as you showed in your MWE it would be pretty easy. Create an algorithm that focuses on the **Month Year Date** columns first i.e. for months there are 12 possibilities (month names), years are all 4 digit numbers and the date column is the day, which is a double digit. So now: `If cell.value = monthName then copy to second column` and `If cell.value = 4digitNumber then copy to third column` and `If cell.value  = 2 digit number then copy to fourth column` and `Else copy to first column` :)

Comment: Is it just date and year that are around the wrong way in some instances or are there other columns with issues?  Easy fix with basic formulas in adjacent cells if it's just these two.

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos Well the algorithm would have to focus on Name Month Year and Date because in some cases the year can be in the name column and vice versa

Comment: @ACCtionMan All the columns have issues so in the Name column I'm having the year Month or Data variables in that column

Comment: Yuck, still doable but complexity goes up especially if you have anyone with the name the same as a month name, eg Jan, May or June?

Comment: @Yigan32 No it wouldn't because you can have unlimited number of names, while Months, Years and Days are known values. Once you sort those three into their columns you just `Else <the last item remaining in the row must be the name>` and that's that

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in new columns with formula, if one has `CONCAT()`:

Name:

```
=CONCAT(IF((ISERROR(--A2:D2))*(ISERROR(--("1 " & A2:D2))),A2:D2,""))
```

Month:

```
=CONCAT(IF((ISERROR(--A2:D2))*(ISNUMBER(--("1 " & A2:D2))),A2:D2,""))
```

Year:

```
=CONCAT(IF((ISNUMBER(--A2:D2))*(LEN(A2:D2)=4),A2:D2,""))
```

Date:

```
=CONCAT(IF((ISNUMBER(--A2:D2))*(LEN(A2:D2)<>4),A2:D2,""))
```

Depending on one's version these may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Hi there Scott, that's not a bad solution in this case. Would you mind explaining the formula for Names and/or Months? `=CONCAT(IF((ISERROR(--A2:D2))*(ISERROR(--("1 " & A2:D2))),A2:D2,""))` or `=CONCAT(IF((ISERROR(--A2:D2))*(ISNUMBER(--("1 " & A2:D2))),A2:D2,""))` Thanks